# What's the correct wildcard syntax to copy TeamCity artifacts to the root of a destination path?

Tags: configuration, teamcity, artifacts

I'm having a small drama with the wildcard syntax in my TeamCity artifact configuration. I want to grab every file matching the pattern myproject.*.dll from any folder and place each DLL in the ***root*** of the artifacts path.

Here's what I've got at present:

```
**/obj/Debug/myproject.*.dll => /
```

This is grabbing all the DLLs but it's putting them inside the same folder structure as the source so rather than ending up with "myproject.web.dll" in the artifacts I get "Web/obj/debug/myproject.web.dll".

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm afraid you cannot do this in an easy way.
You should collect your *.dll locally to a single place, and than use TeamCity's artifacts rule to copy all of them to root directory.

Or, you can enter all paths manually (without ** part)

This is how it works in TC.

Comment: Whilst it's not the answer I would have liked, it does unfortunately seem to be the correct one.

Answer (score 4):

I am not sure you can use the artifact root without it copying the structure. The docs specify

> If target directory is omitted the
>   files are published in the root of the
>   build artifacts.

Can you not just use a designated folder name say dist, would this cause issues? If so what are they!

e.g

```
**/obj/Debug/myproject.*.dll => dist
```

Update - found some more info in the docs

> The files will be published preserving
>   the structure of the directories
>   matched by the wildcard (directories
>   matched by "static" text will not be
>   created). That is, TeamCity will
>   create directories starting from the
>   first occurrence of the wildcard in
>   the pattern.

So if you can be more explicit it may lead to a flatter structure.

Comment: Same deal, you just end up with the entire directory structure in the "dist" folder. In fact, I really don't need the "=> /" syntax if I want the files in the root anyway.

Comment: In terms of why this causes issues, it's simply that it's a large solution with many projects and once the DLLs get captured way down within the folder structure it's a bit harder to easily identify what you have. You need to go traversing down folder trees rather than just being able to see all artifacts at a glance.